# Checking for valid MySQL result resource

Tags: php, mysql, resultset

I have this code:

```
$rows = array();
$res = mysql_query($someQuery);

if(!mysql_errno())
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
        $rows[] = $row;
```

`$someQuery` is an arbitrary query that I write in to a form. The mysql_errno catches the case when I write a mysql query with errors in it. But, I just discovered that when I do a "Delete from table_name" query, it of course is not an error, but at the same time the mysql_fetch_assoc fails with a "Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /blah/blah/file.php on line x".

I've tried to look for it in the manual (maybe I'm just blind...) but is there a function I can use to check if $res is a valid MySQL result resource or not?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysql_fetch_* expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674312/warning-mysql-fetch-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-error)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`if ($res)` should work fine to check if it's a resource.  [is_resource()](http://php.net/is_resource) will determine if its a valid resource at all.

You could also check [mysql_affected_rows](http://php.net/mysql_affected_rows) to try to determine if it's an INSERT/UPDATE/etc

Answer (score 3):

Along with [`is_resource()`](http://php.net/is_resource) you can use [`get_resource_type()`](http://php.net/get_resource_type) to check whether it is a MySQL resource.

```
$res_type = is_resource($res) ? get_resource_type($res) : gettype($res);

if(strpos($res_type, 'mysql') === false) {
    echo 'Invalid resource type: ' . $res_type;
}
```

`get_resource_type()` may return `"mysql link"` or `"mysql link persistent"` depending on your connection type.

Comment: If google brings anyone here, the above warning suppression technique doesn't work for resource type `"odbc link"`.

Answer (score 2):

[`mysql_query()`](http://php.net/mysql_query) returns `true` or `false` so you can check it this way:

```
if($res) {
    // The query succeeded.
}
```

Comment: While this is true for the case the question described, it is a little mis-leading.  mysql_query() returns true or false if the query altered the database in some way (DELETE, INSERT, DROP, etc.).  But if the query is SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, or EXPLAIN, it returns a resource.

Answer (score 2):

Check http://www.lampdocs.com/blog/2010/10/how-to-check-that-a-php-variable-is-a-mysql-resource/ for the solution. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE or DROP via `mysql_query` then it will only return `true` or `false` (depending on success of operation).

I'm not sure what you are expecting the resource to contain in this instance?

If you need the number of affected rows, you can use [`mysql_affected_rows()`](http://php.net/mysql_affected_rows).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps just change the condition to:

```
if(!mysql_errno() && @mysql_num_rows($res) > 0)
```

The conditional will fail if there's no rows, and @ will suppress the warning.