# php mysql select query to retrieve data to accomplish search function

Tags: php, mysql, select

I want to create a *search section* in my website where the user has the ablility to choose between 3 types of searching:   he can   search *by name*, search *by specialization* or search *by location*.

The output will be the first name,  last name,  and profile picture.

The problem is that I do not know how to write the structure  and the queries of this code.

This what i tried to write but it gives me many errors:

- notice : Undefined  index : district
- notice : undefined index : village
- notice : undefined index : sql
- warning :mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1  to be  resource ,
  null

## search.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['login'] != 'true'){
        header("location:index.php");
    }


   $login = ($_SESSION['login']);
   $userid = ($_SESSION['user_id']);
   $login_user = ($_SESSION['username']);
   $fname = ($_SESSION['first_name']);
   $lname = ($_SESSION['last_name']);
   $sessionaddres =($_SESSION['address']);


require_once('for members/scripts/connect.php'); 

// function for selecting names
function nameQuery(){

  $nameData = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user") or die("could not select database");

  while($record = mysql_fetch_array($nameData)){

     echo'<option value="' . $record['user_name'] .  '">' . $record['user_name'] . '</option>';

  }

}



// function for select by specialization

function specializationQuery(){

$specData = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM specialization");

  while($recordJob = mysql_fetch_array($specData)){

     echo'<option value="' . $recordJob['specialization_name'] .  '">' . $recordJob['specialization_name'] . '</option>';

  }


}

if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
    $Sname =$_POST['name']; 
    $Sspec = $_POST['specialization'];
    $Sgov = $_POST['governorate'];
    $Sdist = $_POST['district'];
    $Svillage = $_POST['village'];

    // query  search by name
    if($Sname !=0)
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT first_name, last_name, profile_pic FROM user WHERE user_name ='$Sname'")or die(mysql_error());
    while($getrow = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
        $firstname = $getrow['first_name'];
        $lastname = $getrow['last_name'];
        $profilepic = $getrow['profile_pic'];

        var_dump($firstname);
        var_dump($lastname);
        var_dump($profilepic);


        echo "<ul>
                 <li>
                    '.$firstname'  '' '.$lastname'
                 </li>
                 <li>
                  '.$profilepic'
                 </li>
              </ul>";
    }
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>search page</title>
<link href="style/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function(){
                $("select#district").attr("disabled","disabled");
                $("select#village").attr("disabled","disabled");
                $("select#governorate").change(function(){
                $("select#district").attr("disabled","disabled");
                $("select#district").html("<option>wait...</option>");
                var id = $("select#governorate option:selected").attr('value');
                $.post("select_district.php", {id:id}, function(data){
                    $("select#district").removeAttr("disabled");
                    $("select#district").html(data);
                });
            });
            $("select#district").change(function(){ 
            id = $(this).val(); 
            $("select#village").attr("disabled","disabled");
            $("select#village").html("<option>wait...</option>");
            $.post("select_village.php", {id:id}, function(data){


            $("select#village").removeAttr("disabled");
            $("select#village").html(data);
         });
        });
            $("form#registerform").submit(function(){
                var cat = $("select#governorate option:selected").attr('value');
                var type = $("select#district option:selected").attr('value');
                var village = $("select#village option:selected").attr('value');

            });
    });


</script>
</head>


<body>
<div class="container">
<!--<?php require_once('header.php'); ?>-->
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />

  <!-- <?php require_once('leftsideBar2.php'); ?>-->


   <div id="search-title">Search section</div>
    <div id="search-form">
    <?php include "select.class.php"; ?>
        <form action="search.php" method="post">
         Search By Name:<br />
         <select name="name" >
            <?php nameQuery(); ?>
             <option id="0">-- select By UserName --</option>
             </select>
           <br/><br/>
           Search By Governorate:<br />

        <select id="governorate" name = 'governorate'>
                <?php echo $opt->ShowGovernorate(); ?>
                </select>
           <br /><br/>
           Search by District:<br />

      <select id="district" name="district">
                    <option value="0">choose...</option>
                </select>

           <br /><br/>
           Search by Cities:<br />
           <select id="village" name="village">
                    <option value="0">choose...</option>
                </select>
           <br /><br/>
           Search By Specialization:<br />
           <select name="specialization">
             <option id="0" disabled="disabled">-- select Job --</option>

          <?php specializationQuery(); ?>
          </select>
          <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search"  />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<?php require_once('footer.php'); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: `die("could select database")` seems like a legitimate error.

Comment: ok i change it can you help me with my problem ??

Answer (score 0):

You should check that the request variables in $_POST are set properly using isset:

```
if (isset($_POST["district"])) { $district = $_POST["district"]; }
//etc
```

I'm not seeing a reference to an index named "sql" in this code, you might want to check "select.class.php" which you included later in your search.php

For the last issue, you should check that all queries are valid; if they are not, mysql_query() will not return a result (mysql_query() returns type resource), then mysql_fetch_array() will not be able to get an array (mysql_fetch_array() expects a resource, but you had null).

Comment: you mean sir  i need to do  if isset for each variable???    $sql is the variable of the query   and for the last issue yes i know that i must check for each query if it is valid but i do not know how to write the structure of these query for each type of search

Comment: You should do isset on anything that could be NULL after the request. I could be wrong, but the error message means that there is an array being accessed on the key "sql", not a variable named $sql. I don't know how to help you write queries without some information on what you are trying to accomplish. The query in search.php LOOKS correct but you should check the string to see if $Sname is an empty string.

Comment: I did not see that originally. If $Sname is a string then you should be comparing it to a string, not an integer. That kind of comparison is dangerous.

In your case, that is always being evaluated to false, so mysql_query isn't even executing. Therefore, $sql is null. You should be checking that $sql isn't NULL as well.

Comment: tell me if i did understand you   after i do the query i must check if the query return  valid data so i need to use the **mysql_num_rows()** to check if the result is bigger than 1 ?

Comment: No, you already have enough information. mysql_query() should return a resource. you can check for NULL or its type. See this SO thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/783125/checking-for-valid-mysql-result-resource

edit: sorry, not to mislead you, if mysql_query() is performing a SELECT, like in your case, it should return a resource upon success.

Comment: annn ok so now i get the check and it return teh negative result  with the  3 same errors   thank you for your help can you still help me  with these??

Comment: what you mean by  **it should return a resource upon success.**

Comment: Look at this link: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php and go to the Return Values section, it talks about the return type(s) of the function. You can also look at what a resource is. That's not really important as long as you know what you're expecting to get from a query (for example, you shouldn't try to do fetch_array on a DELETE query because those queries aren't going to return data to you, only true or false)