# Insert Mysql data into HTML table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've found some similar posts on the forum but I still haven't managed to fix it
PS. I'm new in PHP and desperate :@

So I want some basic mysql data into a HTML table. I've found some similar posts and I've tried putting them together and this is what I came up with. I guess i forget some things in order to make it work.

The error I get is: **Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in**

```
CODE: **UPDATED**

$db = "D05000C2";
$query = ("SELECT * FROM FunStreet_bestellingen");
$result = $db -> query($query);
$counter = mysql_num_rows($result);

if($counter > 0){

echo "<table>";
echo "  <tr>";
echo "      <td>Order_id</td>";
echo "      <td>Naam</td>";
echo "      <td>Productnaam</td>";
echo "      <td>Lengtemaat</td>";
echo "      <td>breedtemaat</td>";
echo "      <td>prijs</td>";
echo "  </tr>";

for($i = 0; $i < $counter; $i++){
$row = $result -> fetch_assoc();
echo "  <tr>";
echo "      <td>".$row['order_id']."</td>";
echo "      <td>".$row['naam']."</td>";
echo "      <td>".$row['productnaam']."</td>";
echo "      <td>".$row['lengtemaat']."</td>";
echo "      <td>".$row['breedtemaat']."</td>";
echo "      <td>".$row['prijs']."</td>";
echo "  </tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
}
```

Comment: I highly suggest reading [What have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com) before posting questions. Also, what is happening that is not expected? **PLEASE** give details in your questions.

Comment: where do you call `result($db)`?

Comment: And, `result($db)` looks like it should return something.

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm not familiar with stackoverflow.I'm supposed to insert the data into a html table and i'm pretty new to php...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checking for valid MySQL result resource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/783125/checking-for-valid-mysql-result-resource)

Comment: No worries, we're pretty critical here, but we mean it in the nicest possible way ;) But yeah, you should read [the faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), there are a lot of rules here.

Comment: Sorry, where can I post a new version of my code to show u? Should I update my original post?

Comment: I suggest reading up on [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) as your connection to your database is wrong

Answer (score 5):

Without all of the code, I cannot make a working version. However, I can point out the problem.

You have a function

```
function result($db) {    
    $result = $db -> query("SELECT * FROM FunStreet_bestellingen");
}
```

Which appears to do the job of grabbing the data from the database. The problem is you don't call the function anywhere in your script. Also, this function does not return anything. This will give you the

```
Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource
```

since what is being passed in is most likely `NULL`. I suggest doing the following, either return something and call the function, or just remove it. Calling:

```
function result($db) {    
    return $db -> query("SELECT * FROM FunStreet_bestellingen");
}
$result = result($db);
$counter = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

However, if this is all in one script, I would go to suggest just removing the function.

```
$result = $db -> query("SELECT * FROM FunStreet_bestellingen");

$counter = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `mysqli`, then you can try this:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("hostname", "your_username", "your_password", "D05000C2");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM FunStreet_bestellingen") or die('Unable to run query:' . mysqli_error());

$counter = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($counter > 0) {

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>Order_id</td>";
echo "<td>Naam</td>";
echo "<td>Productnaam</td>";
echo "<td>Lengtemaat</td>";
echo "<td>breedtemaat</td>";
echo "<td>prijs</td>";
echo "</tr>";

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['order_id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['naam'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['productnaam'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['lengtemaat'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['breedtemaat'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['prijs'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>";
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```